# How to raise a KEYEVENT_ENTER?

Tags: android-10

NOTE: I am not writing an android program, I am *using* someone else's program.

It seems that the enter-looking-button on my virtual keyboard isn't raising the enter key event on some websites that I go to.  I'm not entering text - I know that the website is listening for an enter keypress event in order to initiate some behavior.  How can I raise the enter key event with my virtual keyboard?

Comment: ask the creator of that keyboard

Comment: @alecxs I'm just using the stock keyboard

Comment: my keyboard toggles the key automatically depending on which input field the cursor is
https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9gi0.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wigpt.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hx2n.jpg